# How to fix "Field X is never assigned to and will have its default value null"?

Tags: c#, null, field, default-value

I am trying to enter input from the console(street, city, country) but the fields are underlined and display the message(field is never assigned to and will have its value null). I have also created a method SetFullAddress which doesn't work(idk if it is because of that message).

Code inside Address class:

```
public class Address
{
    private string street;
    private string city;
    private string country;

    public Address()
    {
        this.Street = street;
        this.City = city;
        this.Country = country;
    }

    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public string SetFullAddress()
    {
        return ($"Full address: {street} {city} {country}");
    }

    public void DisplayAddress()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Street: {Street}");
        Console.WriteLine($"City: {City}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Country: {Country}");
        Console.WriteLine(SetFullAddress());


    }

}
```

And inside Main method:

```
        Address address = new Address();
        Console.Write("Street: ");
        address.Street = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("City: ");
        address.City = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Country: ");
        address.Country = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine();
        address.DisplayAddress();
```

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy Well I am a beginner, I need clarification and more information. That's why I'm asking. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

```
   public static void Main()
    {

        Console.Write("Street: ");
        string street = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("City: ");
        string city = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Country: ");
        string country = Console.ReadLine();

        Address address = new Address(street, city, country);
        Console.WriteLine();
        address.DisplayAddress();
    }

    public class Address
    {
        private string street;
        private string city;
        private string country;

        public Address(string street, string city, string country)
        {
            this.street = street;
            this.city = city;
            this.country = country;
        }

        public string Street {
            get => street;
            set => street = value;
        }
        public string City {
            get => city;
            set => city = value;
        }
        public string Country {
            get => country;
            set => country = value;
        }

        public string SetFullAddress()
        {
            return ($"Full address: {street} {city} {country}");
        }

        public void DisplayAddress()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Street: {Street}");
            Console.WriteLine($"City: {City}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Country: {Country}");
            Console.WriteLine(SetFullAddress());


        }

    }
```

Comment: The constructor is part of my task so I think I need to use it

Comment: OK, then please refer to TheGeneral's answer.

Comment: @Ada I edited my answer. Please check if it is what you want

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the warnings are you are never using (read assigning values to) the private fields.

```
    private string street;
    private string city;
    private string country;

    public Address()
    {
        this.Street = street;
        this.City = city;
        this.Country = country;
    }

    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
```

You are , instead using Auto Implemented Properties. You can, either safely remove them and rewrite your SetFullAddress method as following (using Auto Implemented Properties)

```
public string SetFullAddress()
{
    return ($"Full address: {Street} {City} {Country}");
}
```

Or you can creating Properties with implicitly typed private backing fields as

```
public string Street 
{ 
    get => street; 
    set => street = value; 
}
public string City
{ 
    get => city; 
    set => city = value; 
}
public string Country
{ 
    get => country; 
    set => country = value; 
}
```

Please be aware that when you are using Auto Implemented properties, compiler creates the backing fields. You can read more on Auto Implemented Properties [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties).

Answer (score 0):

The warning is telling you exactly what is the problem, the following are never assigned

```
private string street;
private string city;
private string country;
```

Maybe you wanted to initialise the actual properties in the constructor

```
//private string street;
//private string city;
//private string country;

public Address(string street, string city, string country)
{
    this.Street = street;
    this.City = city;
    this.Country = country;
}
```

[Compiler Warning (level 4) CS0649](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0649)

> Field 'field' is never assigned to, and will always have its default
>   value 'value'
>
> The compiler detected an uninitialized private or internal field
>   declaration that is never assigned a value.

The following sample generates CS0649:

```
class MyClass  
{  
   Hashtable table;  // CS0649  
   // You may have intended to initialize the variable to null  
   // Hashtable table = null;  

   // Or you may have meant to create an object here  
   // Hashtable table = new Hashtable();  

   public void Func(object o, string p)  
   {  
      // Or here  
      // table = new Hashtable();  
      table[p] = o;  
   }  

   public static void Main()  
   {  
   }  
}
```

Comment: I removed the fields and added three string arguments to the constructor, but now Address address = new Address(); displays an error. I shouldn't enter any information like: Address address = new Address("street", "city", "country"); but let the user input that information from the console, instead. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @Ada remove the construct entirely or add an additional default one `public Address() {}`

Answer (score 0):

If you're not encountering any errors and just want to disable the warnings from that script you caa use `#pragma warning disable 0649`

But don't abuse it, these warnings may help you later.