# How to fix 'Class field is never assigned to' error in C#

Tags: c#, class, field

I'm following a tutorial and while trying to solve one of the challenges I came across these error messages:

> Field 'Data.Age' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value 0
>
> Field 'Data.Month' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null

The code is runnig fine and everything works but I don't know what this error exactly means (because I assigned something to those fields) or how to fix it.

I looked into [How to fix "Field X is never assigned to and will have its default value null"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54031995/how-to-fix-field-x-is-never-assigned-to-and-will-have-its-default-value-null) but didn't understand what's going on.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new Data();

        Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
        data.Name = Console.ReadLine();

        while (data.Name == "")
        {
            data.Name = TryAgain();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("What is your age?");
        data.Age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        while (data.Age == null)
        {
            data.Age = int.Parse(TryAgain());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("What month were you born in?");
        data.Month = Console.ReadLine();

        while (data.Month == "")
        {
            data.Month = TryAgain();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Your name is: {0}", data.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Your age is: {0}", data.Age);
        Console.WriteLine("Your birth month is: {0}", data.Month);

    }

    static string TryAgain()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You didn't type anything, please try again:");
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Data
{
    public string Name;
    public int? Age;
    public string Month;
}
```

Comment: Code in the question does not show any warnings/errors. Please verify if you posted correct code for the questions you are asking. See [MCVE] for guidance.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov So I restarted VS and now the error is gone... Didn't know this might be a thing. I will try that first in the future. Do I delete the question?

Comment: Good news then, however try to enter a wrong value for your age like "my age is twenty" and see what happens

Comment: @AlexLeo Yeah, TryParse and try catch statements were next in the tutorial. So I'm working on that right now :)